# How to make Telegram InlineKeyboardMarkup work in an Azure Container Instance

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, connectivity, azure-container-instances

I designed a messaging system that sends Telegram messages. I recently added a button for a user to stop an alert. While the button works perfectly in a local environment, when deploying to an Azure Container Instance, the button is unresponsive. Below my messaging code:

```
def send_telegram_message(bot_token, chat_id, message,root_address):
    url = url_bot_telegram + bot_token + '/sendMessage'

    # Creating a button for stopping monitoring
    stop_button = InlineKeyboardButton(f"Stop Alerts for Address {root_address}", callback_data=f'stop_{root_address}')
    custom_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[stop_button]]).to_json()
    
    payload = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
        'text': message,
        'parse_mode': 'Markdown',
        'reply_markup': custom_keyboard
   
    }
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        logger.info(f"HTTP Error: {errh}")
        return False
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        logger.info(f"Error Connecting: {errc}")
        return False
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        logger.info(f"Timeout Error: {errt}")
        return False
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        logger.info(f"Something went wrong: {err}")
        return False

    # check if the request was successful
    if response.json()["ok"]:
        logger.info("Message sent successfully") 
        return
    else:
        logger.info(f"Telegram API returned an error: {response.json()['description']}")
        return False
    
async def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    root_address = query.data.split('_')[1]
    # Instead of calling stop_monitoring directly, put root_address in the removal_queue
    removal_queue.put(root_address)

    # Send a new message
    await context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        text=f'Alerts stopped for address: {root_address}',
        reply_to_message_id=query.message.message_id  # This line makes the new message a reply to the original message
     )


def stop_monitoring(removal_queue, all_transactions_df, all_identified_addresses):
    while not removal_queue.empty():
        try:
            # .... some code irrelevant for the question

def telegram_polling():
    # Create a new event loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    # Set the event loop for this thread
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    # Apply the nest_asyncio patch
    nest_asyncio.apply(loop)

    async def run_telegram_polling():
        app = Application.builder().token(bot_token).build()

        # Create a handler for callback queries (i.e., button clicks)
        button_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(button)
        
        # Register the handler with your Application object
        app.add_handler(button_handler)
        
        await app.run_polling()

    try:
        # Run the async function until it completes
        loop.run_until_complete(run_telegram_polling())
    finally:
        # Close the event loop
        loop.close()
```

My thought is that is has something to do with connectivity to the ACI (firewall, inbound settings, etc). I deploy to the ACI like this (removed all the sensitive information):

```
az container create --resource-group alertsystem --name 11aci --image 11acr.azurecr.io/m11alertapp:latest --cpu 1 --memory 1 --registry-login-server 11acr.azurecr.io --registry-username 11acr --registry-password 12245+ACRDMbYE1 --environment-variables API_KEY=124253 DEBANK_API_KEY=124345 CHAT_ID=-35532 BOT_TOKEN=355:555-Ra0wJBQxl7z8OCIbFtc RUNNING_IN_ACI=true TZ=Europe/Amsterdam --azure-file-volume-account-name storagealertsystem --azure-file-volume-account-key 223553/K/7vghhmRvCcCC5bxSeuTjUthmXDHdsx+iyzE8DGpo/+AStZsDgHQ== --azure-file-volume-share-name fs-alertsystem --azure-file-volume-mount-path mnt/data
```

It would be great if someone could take a look at it.

Comment: I think it has to do with the second thread. I'm running two threads locally like this:

```    # Create and start a thread for the Telegram polling logic
    telegram_thread = threading.Thread(target=telegram_polling, daemon=False)
    telegram_thread.start()

``` 

 This entire telegram thread is not being executed in the ACI.